# Column names return lowercase in aws glue

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am new to AWS Glue, and have created job through crawler which point the source target CSV-file in S3-bucket.

The CSV-file contains following columns as:

```
userId  jobTitleName    firstName   lastName    preferredFullName   employeeCode    region
```

Now during the job execution, it throws following error
`Key error: userid' not exist`. As notified, the issue looks the case sensitive issue. so as per the glue-document, I created mapping for the schema

```
mappingsSchema=[('userid', 'integer', 'userId', 'integer'),
                 ('jobtitlename', 'string', 'jobTitleName', 'string'),
                 ('firstname', 'string', 'firstName', 'string'),
                 ('lastname', 'string', 'lastName', 'string'),
                 ('preferredfullName', 'string', 'preferredFullname', 'string'),
                 ('employeecode', 'string', 'employeeCode', 'string'),
                 ('region', 'string','region', 'string')]
mapped_dynamic_frame_read=dynamic_frame_read.apply_mapping(mappings = mappingsSchema, case_sensitive = True, transformation_ctx = "tfx")
##And converting to the spark df
df = mapped_dynamic_frame_read.toDF()
```

Still I'mm getting the same mentioned error. 
How can resolve this kind of issue?

Comment: looks like there is no data read into your dynamic frame. you can verify the same by checking mappingsSchema.count() or mappingsSchema .show()

Comment: Hi @Dunedan, i see data being read from 'mappingsSchema .show() '. But the 'userID' returns null.. Let me know what changes need to be done to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you reading the csv file via the glue table representation ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Emerson The issue was with mappings in which column names were wrongly specified against the schema definition. Now it's fixed and working fine.. Thanks